# Jenkins - Execute commands over ssh by passing username and password at run time

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Is it possible to pass username and password as Jenkins parameter to connect remote host using SSH?

Multiple user want to execute single Jenkins job with their credential to connect ssh over remote host. It will not be possible to use key mechanism so need to use username and password.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Install `sshpass` on the slave machine where Jenkins job will be run and use `sshpass` to ssh using username/password.
Source : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

Comment: Thanks for the help. My slave is on windows machine so I am not able to use sshpass.

We have try to use Putty and plink but from Jenkins it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Using plink utility from putty we are able to pass user name and password dynamically.

`plink.exe -ssh %user%@%host% -pw %password% -m shellscript`